# How to make multiple payments on one order by amount

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, invoice, payment-methods

I have two scenarios with a common thread.

One is the use of a gift card, i.e. a $50 Visa Gift Card, with a $53 order.
Ideally the customer would select payment type and amount $50. The order still needs a $3 payment. Then the customer could make payment via another credit card or other method. Order is fully paid and ready to ship.

In another scenario it would be the customer is making a deposit and the second payment method would be check/bank transfer etc.. the Order would not be fully paid. Later in admin the payment would be recorded.

This is not available in the admin,  only invoicing for a unit of product.  If customer orders multiple items and selects a non-completing payment method like "check",  you can invoice for some of them and later for the rest but by qty only not $amount.

I have searched for extensions and topics in various forums.

Comment: Every time I see such a question, I have to warn. Very be careful with this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11613/217

Comment: Fabian, thanks for the comment I agree now that I have looked at this. The customer is looking elsewhere to solve their problem...