# Partial payment

Tags: payment

is there an opportunity to pay for the product with part of part .  the buyer has the money to a one card that is not enough to pay for, but he has another card and wants to pay together. 
I want to create system for this.  Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want this, except you have a lot of time for reading and learning or you are an expert or want to get one for shared transactions.

1. Magento doesn't do this out of the box.

Why this is so hard to implement I explained here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11613/217

Answer (score 0):

If you have configuration knowledge you can make this by custom . Make the payment pending during recurring access.