# Multiple payment methods on one transaction

Tags: checkout, payment-methods

We have a Gift Card module we wrote and the custom has now required that we make the Gift Card a Payment method. We will then need to allow for two forms of payment on a single transaction. I thought this would be a common thing but it is proving harder to find a solution.

Is there an existing module or am I searching the wrong way?

EDIT:
Basically we want the following:

Customer checkout : balance is $100 
Customer makes payment from the following:

Type1(Visa) $70
Type2(Mastercard) $30

Comment: Magento Enterprise

Comment: You need to be very very careful about this, because what you want to do is a distributed transaction and it is hard to implement. I wrote something about this here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11613/217

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt We started on a module, I will let you know how it goes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have created a new payment method for our gift card, we then take the following steps in Magento.

1) Retrieve Gift card Balance through Ajax call

2) We then display message as per available balance.

If balance is sufficient - "Please continue to confirm order"

If balance is not sufficient - "Please insert credit card info in order to pay XX remaining amount"

3) Customer fills in CC info and then presses continue.

4) At the place order step, when the customer clicks on place order button, we will Authenticate GC amount and check latest available balance in capture function of Payment Gateway, if it is same as Payment step then we can directly capture the remaining amount from the credit card.

If a difference arises in GC balance then we show a message and confirm with customer that they would like to pay XX amount from CC or wanted to use new Credit card for all remaining amount.

And it works!

The same logic should work with Money Order/Check + Credit Card (Since we won't have to check the balance on the Check

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a "rewards" module, where you can pay partially using virtual currency (points) would be a solution?

Comment: This the problem was that it shows as a discount, we need it to show as a payment type

Comment: It seems there were some "customer credits" extensions at the connect. Do they all offer discounts, not payment methods?