# Store Credit for a customer

Tags: store-credit

please tell how to configuration store credit in megento commerce and also give me a code for that and explain where is put tis code in magento.

please tell how to configuration store credit in megento commerce and also give me a code for that and explain where is put tis code in magento.

Comment: You want really think about this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/customers-add-funds-to-their-balance-how/11613#11613

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Store Credit a.k.a Customer Credit extensions available through [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=store%20credit&pl=0).  Each extension has its own set of instructions for installation and configuration.  You will want to look through those options and find the most appropriate option for your store.